# Angular Frontend - Save in an Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. So sorry if that's an obvious thing, that I'm supposed to know. 
I'm getting a String[] from the backend and I want to save various strings in it, by typing them in a mat-form-field in the front end. 
Somehow the changes won't show up in the DB. 
All other fields (request only a String) are working fine. So I guess I'm doing something wrong in my html

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="Placeholder" *ngIf="name$"> // this works, and i'm able to see my saved changes in the backend
     <mat-form-field class="example">  
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="data$.lastname">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

---

```
<div  class="Placeholder"  *ngIf="name$" > //somehow I cannot "save" 
      <mat-form-field class="example">
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="name$.abc" >
      </mat-form-field>
```

---

This is my name.ts:

```
lastname: string;

firstname: string;

abc:string[];
```

---

my save-button:

```
    <button mat-button class="save" (click)="update()">save</button>
```

my name.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Name } from './name';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NameService {

  URL = 'placeholder';
  ID: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, router: Router) { }

  getData(headerID: string): Observable<Name> {
    this.ID = headerID;       
    return this.http.get<Data>(`URL`);
  }

  update(name: Name): Observable<Name> {                              
    return this.http.put<Name>(`ID}`, name, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('update', name)));
  }

}
```

and my name.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { Name } from './name';
import { NameService } from './name.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { flatMap, subscribeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name',
  templateUrl: './name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name.component.css']
})

export class NameComponent implements OnInit {

 name$: Name;

    update(): void {
      this.nameService.updateName(this.name$)
      .subscribe(name => this.name$ = name);
    }
```

I hope it's more or less understandable. And I appreciate any sorts of help!

Comment: We're going to have to see some code. How are you attempting to save the new data?

Comment: An `input` has a single `value` attribute that takes a `string`. So Angular takes your array and converts it to a comma-delimited string. Or perhaps it doesn't know what to do with it and just ignores it. Either way, you're going to have to provide the conversion between array and string.

Comment: Your trying to use an [(ngModel)] to set an array field? what is the desired outcome?? do you want to strings to the array or do you want .abc to be a string?

Comment: I want to be able to save more than one string in the name array (like street + city i.e.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a `[(ngModel)]` incorrectly

what you will need to do is

In your component create a new variable `abcValue`

```
abcValue: string;
```

then in your template you will need to change your [(ngModel)] to be

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="abcValue" >
```

then you are going to have to create a new function that will add your `abcValue` to your `$name.abc` array

```
storeAbcValue() {
  // check to see if abc exists / is array
  if (this.name$.abc) {
    // push the abcValue
    this.name$.abc.push(this.abcValue);
  } else {
    // create new array and store in abc
    this.name$.abc = [this.abcValue];
  }
  // clear abcValue
  this.abcValue = null;
}
```

so on your update function you will have to do something like

```
update() {
  this.storeAbcValue();
  // ...
}
```